# Trying to call back a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to call back a function which creates a list of random numbers.  Then after that I want to take the mean of those random numbers.

```
    import random
    def randomNumbers(n):
        myList = []
        needMoreNumbers = True
        while (needMoreNumbers):
            randomNumber = int(random.random() * 10)
            myList.append(randomNumber)
            n = n -1
            if (n < 1):
                needMoreNumbers = False
        return myList
```

That's the first part of the code.
Here's what I have next:

```
    import random
    def calculateAverage(n):
        return sum(mylist)/len(myList)
```

I also need to be able to print both functions.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Trying to use the function randomNumbers(n) to create the list of random numbers.  Then I want to find the mean of the random numbers for the second function calculateAverage(n)

Comment: Oh, so you want to know how to call a function? It's as simple as `myList = randomNumbers(n)`

Answer (score 0):

calculateAverage should take myList as an argument, not n.

Also check the case of the variable, you had `mylist`  and `myList` used interchangeably.

In Python2. calculateAverage is doing integer division. You need to cast the integers as floats, so you are doing floating point division.

```
import random
def randomNumbers(n):
    myList = []
    needMoreNumbers = True
    while (needMoreNumbers):
        randomNumber = int(random.random() * 10)
        myList.append(randomNumber)
        n = n -1
        if (n < 1):
            needMoreNumbers = False
    return myList

def calculateAverage(myList):
    return float(sum(myList))/len(myList)


myList = randomNumbers(10)
print calculateAverage(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the same thing..

```
from random import randint as rng

nums = [rng(0, 10) for _ in range(n)]
sum(nums) / n
```